# Placing Annotations from multiple lists on one map

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

Let me preface this by saying I'm a complete newbie to Swift. I've been messing around with MapKit and am trying to add multiple annotations to a Map with different symbols representing each category of annotations.

To clarify, I have 2 arrays (list1 and list2). Both of these arrays contain Pin objects as defined below:

```
struct Pin: Identifiable{
        let id = UUID()
        let name: String
        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    }
```

I want to add locations from both list1 and list2 on the map as annotations, but use different SF symbols to indicate which list the point was sourced from.

So far, I am able to display points from just one of the lists.

```swift
struct MapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top){
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: list1) {
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: $0.coordinate){
                        Image(systemName: "house").foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
            }
```

To implement the different annotations I considered concatenating list1 and list2 but that wouldn't allow me to use different symbols for points from each list.

My end goal is to use toggle switches to show/hide annotations based on the state of the button.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this approach, where you concatenate `list1 + list2`, and test the item is contained in one of the list (list1):

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: list1 + list2) { item in
    MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate){
        if list1.contains(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
            Image(systemName: "house").foregroundColor(.blue)// <-- here for list1
        } else {
            Image(systemName: "globe").foregroundColor(.red) // <-- here for list2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried this out and it works great! Quick question though, would the contains operation be slow if my lists had a large number of elements?

Comment: try with large lists and let us know if performance is not adequate using your current `Pin` model.
 If it is a problem, you could modifying `Pin` with an `id` that represents the list type.
 For example, `id < 100000` is in `list1`, greater than that number is in `list2`.
 Then it is easy to test, `if item.id > 100000 {....}`. Alternatively add a list number in your `Pin` struct, and test for that.

Comment: Definitely, will try that and let you know. I’m assuming I could use the same concept and define a field in `Pin` that identifies which category the Pin belongs to. Not sure why I didnt think of that earlier

Comment: yes, you could even go further, add to `Pin` a field `let imgName: String` that has the name of the SF, eg `house`, then you don't have to test for anything, just use: `Image(systemName: item.imgName).foregroundColor(.blue)`